# Copy files from remote server to google cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

How would I copy files from a remote server to a google bucket? For example,

`gcloud compute scp username@server:/path/to/file gs://my-bucket`

This method gives the error: `All sources must be local files when destination is remote.`

Additionally, gsutil only provides support for cp and not scp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also directly execute `gsutil` command on your GCE VM (Most VM images have Cloud SDK preinstalled). For example:

```
gcloud compute ssh user@server --zone my_zone \
  --command='gsutil cp path/to/my_file gs://MY_BUCKET'
```

Note that for this to work your service account associated with VM must have appropriate access scope to GCS. If you run

```
gcloud beta compute instances describe my_instance --zone my_zone \
  --format="value(serviceAccounts.scopes)"
```

It will show list of scopes set for VM service account. Make sure you have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`. If not you can use 
[set-scopes beta command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/set-scopes) to reset them or go to console and edit VM in question.

Comment: Ah, good idea, that is much more efficient than piping everything through the local host.  Only caveat, just remember that this will use the gsutil configuration on the GCE VM, rather than the local configuration.  In particular it will likely use the GCE VM's service account credential instead of your personal credentials.  This isn't necessarily bad, just something to be aware of.  (It might even be preferred if your personal credentials don't have direct access to the bucket, which is a good security measure.)

Answer (score -1):

gsutil supports streaming data, so you can try to pipe the data in.

Not 100% certain this works with arbitrary binary data (and I'm on a phone so I can't test it)

```
gcloud compute ssh username@server --command='cat /path/to/file' | gsutil cp - gs://my-bucket
```