# Copying files from remote (non GCE) server to google cloud platform bucket over SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to copy files from a remote server to google cloud storage bucket over SSH? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875499/copy-files-from-remote-server-to-google-cloud-bucket) question outlines how to copy files from a google compute engine instance to google cloud storage which is not what I need.

The files are too large to download to my local machine before uploading them. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
ssh -p 2455 skiventist@myremoteserver | gsutil cp -r /path/to/remote_folder :gs//mybucket
```

Error:

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: /path/to/remote_folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't matter if it's GCE or another server, they are both remote servers. you need to:

1- ssh into your remote server

2- make sure that you have gsutil installed and that you are authorized to manage the bucket.

3- copy the files to that remote server:
`gsutil cp -r /path/to/remote_folder gs//mybucket`

you can use also `-m` flag which will perform a parallel multi-threaded/multi-processing and make the transfer even faster.

check [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) for more info

Comment: Ok thank you. I needed to install glcoud sdk on the remote server.